# What's the most reliable script to return the IP address of real local ethernet links

Tags: linux, networking, ip

For some tunnelling & binding scripts, I need to find a (any) local (non-loopback) actual Ethernet link interface and its IP address.

**Note** this is a dev environment - on my Linux laptop - and this configuration is dynamic (could be Wifi, Ethernet etc)

**Note** I've got loads of docker and kubernetes subsystems running and consequently there are lots of bridges, virtual interfaces etc.

Here's what I have so far:

`nmcli` can give me wifi devices:

```
nmcli d  | grep wifi | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

(But not hardware link-local Ethernet as nmcli's reported type for some virtual interfaces is also 'ethernet')

From this I could (a) dodge through some brittle JQ

```
ip -br -j a show dev $DEV | jq -r .[1].addr_info[0].local
```

*urgh*

or, [xkcd://208](https://www.xkcd.com/208/) my way to success?

```
ip -br a show dev $DEV | perl -nle 'print $1 if $_ =~ /.+ ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/'
```

Considerations:

- `ip` has a `type` filter, but not one for actual hw
- I've looked at `nmcli`, `ip`, `ethtool`, `netstat` : any others?

Answer (score 1):

[Recent enough](https://lwn.net/Articles/738897/) (~ Nov 2017) *iproute2* tools provide a `-j[son]` format output, as you already tested. Together with the `-d[etails]` option, there's plenty information available, in an output designed to be parsed.

It appears real interfaces don't display a `"linkinfo"`object (and associated `"info_kind"` key, which is the type of interface: *bridge*, *veth*, etc. Likewise without JSON output those interfaces don't have the 3rd line every other virtual interface (ok except loopback) have, which start with their type: *bridge* etc.). So just testing for `"link_type": "ether"` and lack of `"linkinfo"` should keep only real ethernet interfaces (which Wifi interfaces are part of). Of course there are limits: if you create a [*mac80211_hwsim*](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MAC80211_HWSIM.html) device, chance are it will look real, since it's simulating a device (rather than just an interface).

So using a specialized JSON processing tool that you already mention in your question: [jq](https://manpages.debian.org/jq/jq.1) (reading its [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) page was enough to craft this generic answer), I wrote this:

```
ip -details -json address show | \
    jq --join-output '.[] |
        if ."link_type" == "ether" and ."linkinfo" == null and (."addr_info" | length) > 0 then
            ."ifname" ,
            (."addr_info"[]|
                if ."family" == "inet" or ."family" == "inet6" then
                    " " + ."local"
                else
                    empty
                end), "\n"
        else
            empty
        end'
```

output example (redacted):

```
 eth0 192.168.2.2 2001:db8:dead:beef:3116:312b:e620:3596 2001:db8:dead:beef:123:4567:89ab:cdef fe80::123:4567:89ab:cdef 
 wlan0 192.168.3.2 2001:db8:dead:bee5:dfa:a10b:df26:ef3e 2001:db8:dead:bee5:cdef:89ab:4567:123 fe80::cdef:89ab:4567:123
```

Notes

- If you want to keep *veth* interfaces (else containers will probably never show anything) you can replace `."linkinfo" == null` with `(."linkinfo" == null or ."linkinfo"."info_kind" == "veth")`.
- To visually read the command's direct JSON output, better use `ip -details -pretty -json address show`.

Answer (score 0):

Start with `ifconfig`
Say `ens3` is the interface. `ip addr show ens3` will show all the information for that interface. Then do a grep with `inet` to filter ipaddresses. I guess you want to filter out ipv4 only then, do a grep with `inet\b` else `inet6` for ipv6 address. 
To print the ipaddress field do a `awk '{print $2}'` which prints the second portion of the inet.

```
ip addr show ens3 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Now you have address with the masking, if you want to discard the masking include `cut -d/ -f1` which will discard the masking portion.

```
ip addr show ens3 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

Put it in a bash script and run whenever you need it.

Comment: And what if I don't know the interface?

Comment: If I am unsure I do a `cat /proc/net/dev` to find out the running interfaces. Only one of them would be the hardware local interface.

Comment: Sure thing, but that is my question.  Which are hardware and which are software. E.g. I currently have (1 or 2 wireless nics), 0-2 wired nics (they change depending on which office I'm in) and others have different adapters.  I need to find these, excluding the follow: 4 bridges, 21 veths, 1 ppp, 1 tun, 1 x cni, 1xflannel, which are interfaces that I cannot bind a local tunnel endpoint to

Comment: Can you share a result of the ifconfig or `cat /proc/net/dev` then I can write a script to filter.

Comment: Do an `ip route show`. The 'Default' is your route and local HW address.

Comment: I'm sorry Nazia.  Typically, my current default is a tun0 VPN tunnel link. :/  (there is a hw default with a higher route metric, but it'll need some brittle munging to extract which is which automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a switch on an existing utility program that returns this.

But it turns out that the file `/sys/class/net/<iface>/device` seems to exist if it's an actual hardware interface.  (I'm sure this could be a wrong assertion)

Here is a python snippet to regex out IP addresses from configured interfaces with such `sysfs` entries.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import re

for dev in os.listdir('/sys/class/net'):
    if os.path.isdir('/sys/class/net/' + dev + '/device'):
        try:
            print(re.search(' ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})', os.popen('ip -br a show dev ' + dev).read()).groups()[0])
        except:
            pass
```

[1] https://gist.github.com/robshep/5daea97bd9f438d69c3e23e3ad02c0bd